# How to remove background color of a window in flutter windows project?

Tags: windows, flutter, user-interface, winapi

I am trying to create UI with rounded corners on windows platform but there is still black background in the window. How can I remove background color completely?

I have created container with rounded corner decoration to achieve this.

Code

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
  child: Buttons()
);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include the full code for this screen?

Answer (score 0):

try to use ClipRRect:

```
ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
         Radius.circular(10.0)),
    child: Container(
      width: 100.0,
      height:100.0,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),
  )
```

Comment: This doesn't work as the background is coming from win32 api side.